# how can create table for Year and month

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can i have create table for year and month
 table name :**Year** and insert data 
2014 2015 2018 2019 2020 2021
and another table name
**Month** and inserting data
January,February,March,April,

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers. I flagged this question for closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Years(
 year int
);

CREATE TABLE Months(
month varchar(15)
);

DECLARE @cnt INT = 2014;

WHILE @cnt < 2021
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO Years(year) VALUES(@cnt);
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;
```

For table Months you can add it one by one,

```
INSERT INTO Months(month) VALUES('JANURARY');
.
.
.
```

Comment: why need this function ? `DECLARE @cnt INT = 2014;
WHILE @cnt < 2021
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO Years(year) VALUES(@cnt);
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;`

Comment: If you want to insert years one by one this is your choice,basically this is not function this is a loop, it increases year in each turn and insert the year to table. For example you want to insert between 1900 to 2016, you cannot insert one by one you need to do it in a loop